# Apache POI: how to set cell formula to a name of another sheet?

Tags: excel, apache-poi, named-ranges

Am I doing it wrong, or is this a bug / limitation of POI?

I'm getting `FormulaParseException: Cell reference expected after sheet name at index 8`.

It works without the sheet qualifier, but then the formula will not work if copy pasted to another sheet.

And I need sheet-scoped names because multiple sheets defined the same names.

```
  File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop/Test.xlsx");
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
  Name name = workbook.createName();
  name.setNameName("NameForA1");
  name.setSheetIndex(workbook.getSheetIndex(sheet));
  name.setRefersToFormula("'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$1");
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue("This is A1");
  Cell b1 = row.createCell(1);
  //      b1.setCellFormula("'Sheet1'!NameForA1"); // throws exception
  b1.setCellFormula("Sheet1!NameForA1"); // throws exception
  //      b1.setCellFormula("NameForA1"); // works
  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(file));
  Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

[image: screenshot]

But I need:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Create a file in Excel with the formula you want, read that back in Apache POI, and see what exact form Excel encodes it in? (What is shown in the UI is often different to what goes in the file....)

Comment: Thanks, good tip for the next problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, was a bug in 3.10.x. Works in 3.17.

Leaving the question. Maybe the example is useful to someone.